# kubectl: Cannot start: No such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to download (copy) a .tar.gz file from a kubernetese pod into my local computer.

I tried:

```
kubectl cp rasa-core-cz-ret-deployment-7958c6887c-62mqg:app/models/20211101-142745.tar.gz ~/Desktop
```

Error:

> tar: app/models/20211101-142745.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or
> directory

It's weird because I can see the file on the path above in either Octant or executing

```
kubectl exec -it rasa-core-cz-ret-deployment-7958c6887c-62mqg /bin/bash
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: try using a full path to the remote file?

Comment: @AnthonySottile What is the full path?

Comment: for instance if you've got a file `foo` and your working directory is `/home/me/bar` the full path would be `/home/me/bar/foo`